# Results differ when running .py vs .ipynb. Getting a list from pynb as expected but none type from .py

Tags: python-3.x, jupyter-notebook, multiprocessing

I am using VS code to run both files. When running the code as a .py the result from the pool.map function is of none type. Oddly enough, when I run the type function to prove it, it says that it is a list function. When I try to do any kind of list methods on it, I get 'NoneType' object is not iterable.

the first image is of how I want it to work

the second image is showing the .py file showing it type as list

the third is showing how it changes to type of none

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/OPE34.png)

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fDMlS.png)

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/yY8JR.png)

I have also created a function in a notebook and then referenced the function from a .py file and am still getting the result as a none type.

```
import pypyodbc
import pandas as pd
from sqlalchemy import create_engine
import time
import os
import gender_guesser.detector as gender
import multiprocessing  
from multiprocessing import Pool
import defs
import numpy as np 


results = None
if __name__ == '__main__':
    t0 = time.time()
    
    pool = Pool()
    instance = tuple(range(1,7))
    results = pool.map(defs.run_sql, instance)
    
    t1 = time.time()
    
    print(t1 - t0)    
    print(len(results))

print(type(results))
print(type(results[1]))
```

Comment: I think I found it out, it seems as when it runs the multiple processes, it returns an empty variable until all processes have been completed. Which is not how the Jupyter notebook works. I just put an if statement checking to see if the length is greater than 0